# How to calculate Expected Value in this Case?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Given $2$ random variables $X, Y$ S.T: $X \sim \operatorname{Exp}(2)$ and $E(Y|X=x)=3x+1$

I want to calculate $E(XY)$

---

My Approach:

I know that $E(X)=0.5$, $\operatorname {var}(X)=0.25$, Plus: $E(Y|X)=3X+1$ which means: $E(Y)=E(E(Y|X))=E(3X+1)=2.5$

So $E(X)E(Y)=0.5\times 2.5=1.25$

I know that $E(XY)\geq E(X)E(Y)$ but I'm stuck here. How can I continue?

Comment: $E[XY]=E[XE[Y|X]]=2\int_{[0,\infty)}x(3x+1)e^{-2x}dx$

Comment: @Snoop so it's equal to: E(X*(3X+1)) = E(3X^2+X) = 3E(X^2)+E(X) = 3*0.5+0.5 = 2?

Comment: Yes indeed @Algo

Comment: @Snoop kindly just copy paste so I can accept it, and I would appreciate if you could prove that []=[[|]]

Comment: The [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) would give $E[XY] =E[E[XY \mid X]]$ and that is $E[X \,E[Y \mid X]]$

Comment: @Algo you can find the basic properties of conditional expectation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties) as a reference. Proofs can be found in textbooks such as [Klenke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties) Th 8.14